# ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'textutils' in Django

Tags: python, django, importerror

urls.py file:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'textutils'
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Could you show whole error message?

Comment: I think you need to replace `from . import views` by `from views import *` ?